# Как правильно работать со списком checkbox'ов?

Tags: javascript, html

Это фрагмент таблицы с суммами для загрузки в БД. При загрузке (в параметрах хранимой процедуры БД) у каждого банка есть свой параметр, который передается в атрибуте чекбокса: value.
Мне нужно, чтобы при клике на одном из чекбоксов галка устанавливалась или снималась на всех чекбоксах с таким значением value (и при снятии галки со всех чекбоксов с одинаковым value цвет ячейки подсвечивается красным, а если снова поставить галку - то фон ячейки становится белым). Я реализовала это через атрибуты в обработчике клика на чекбоксе:

```js
function have_check(elem) {
  var param_value = elem.value;
  var elems_group = document.querySelectorAll('input[value=\'' + param_value +
    '\']');

  if (elem.hasAttribute('checked')) {
    for (var i = elems_group.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      elems_group[i].removeAttribute('checked');
      elems_group[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = elems_group.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      elems_group[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      elems_group[i].setAttribute('checked', true);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Дата</th>
    <th>Сборщик</th>
    <th>Сумма</th>
    <th>Загрузить</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13.05.2018</td>
    <td>Сбербанк</td>
    <td>337.35</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>18.05.2018</td>
    <td>Сбербанк</td>
    <td>248.9</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21.05.2018</td>
    <td>Сбербанк</td>
    <td>717.6</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22.05.2018</td>
    <td>Сбербанк</td>
    <td>723.45</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22.05.2018</td>
    <td>Альфабанк</td>
    <td>723.45</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>24.05.2018</td>
    <td>Альфабанк</td>
    <td>655.13</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21.05.2018</td>
    <td>ВТБ-24</td>
    <td>356.19</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="3_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23.05.2018</td>
    <td>ВТБ-24</td>
    <td>554.20</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="3_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Все бы ничего, но если последовательно кликать на 1-ый, потом 2-ой, потом 3-й и потом 4-й чекбокс, то видно, что флажки в группе с value= '1_2' начинают хаотично выделяться и сниматься. В общем, работает не так как надо, хотя цвет ячейки меняется правильно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может эту одновременную установку/снятие флажков для группы надо не через атрибут, а через свойство делать? Или в коде у меня какие-то ошибки, из-за которых программа ведет себя не так, как хотелось бы?

Comment: отформатируйте чтобы можно было читать

Comment: "... то видно, что флажки ..." не видно ((((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вкратце, то проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь работать с состоянием не через **свойство**, а через **атрибут**.

Давайте пройдёмся по шагам и поймём, что происходит. Чтобы цвет не сбивал вас с толку, отключите его изменение и следите только за состоянием чекбоксов.

Перед началом следует рассказать о двух важных моментах, которые в русскоязычном сегменте интернета почему-то не освещены.

### Флаг изменённого состояния

[Согласно спецификации](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#concept-input-checked-dirty-flag) инпут имеет булевый флаг изменённого состояния (*dirty checkedness flag*), что-то вроде пломбы, по которой можно проверить, менял ли пользователь состояние чекбокса. При загрузке страницы он равен false.

### HTML-атрибут ≠ DOM-свойство

У элементов есть свойства и атрибуты, это разные сущности. Зачастую их значения связываются между собой, но, есть много но. Например, атрибут `id` связывается со свойством `id`, поэтому вы можете написать `elem.id = 'newId'` и увидеть изменения в DOM. Однако, редактируя текст в `<input type="text">`, вы не заметите изменений атрибута `value`, поскольку тот синхронизируется со свойством `defaultValue`.

И наконец, главное.

**Состояние** элемента отражается через **свойство**. В случае с чекбоксом текущее состояние (*вкл*/*выкл*) можно получить и записать, обратившись к свойству `elem.checked`. Давайте посмотрим, как работает ваш код «на атрибутах» и как его можно переписать «на свойствах».

---

Итак, последовательно прокликаем 4 чекбокса Сбербанка.

1. В вашем случае сначала происходит клик по первому чекбоксу, меняющий состояние и *dirty checkedness flag* (он становится true). И только затем выполняется ваша функция. Предварительный итог до выполнения функции:

   ⬜️ ☑️ ☑️ ☑️

   1.1. В функции вы проверяете, имеет ли элемент атрибут `checked`, ошибочно предполагая, что изменение состояния инпута должно влиять и на атрибут, однако такой зависимости просто не предусмотрено. Вы можете убедиться в этом, создав обычный `<input type="checkbox" checked>`, кликнув по нему и проверив в инспекторе, что стало с атрибутом (спойлер: ничего). Итог: проверка на наличие атрибута проходит успешно, т. к. он был изначально в коде.

   1.2. Далее по коду вы удаляете атрибут `checked` у инпутов с тем же значением. И снова [обратимся к спецификации](http://the-input-element:attr-input-checked-5): при удалении атрибута `checked` браузер должен сам изменить состояние на *false*, **но только при условии, что флаг изменённого состояния равен *false*.** Итог:

   ⬜️ ⬜️ ⬜️ ⬜️
2. Теперь вы делаете клик по второму чекбоксу. Его состояние меняется на отмеченное, флаг изменённого состояния становится *true*. Предварительный итог:

   ⬜️ ☑️ ⬜️ ⬜️

   2.1. Т. к. у всех чекбоксов Сбербанка атрибут checked был удалён в п. 1.2, в функции вы подаете в условие `else`.

   2.2. Здесь чекбоксам задаётся атрибут `checked`. При добавлении атрибута также [должен проверяться](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element:attr-input-checked-4) флаг изменённого состояния, поэтому браузер изменит состояние на вкл только у тех 2-х чекбоксов, у которых флаг ещё равен *false*. Итог:

   ⬜️ ☑️ ☑️ ☑️
3. Клик по третьему чекбоксу. Его состояние становится *выкл*, а флаг `dirty checkedness flag` — *true*. Предварительный итог:

   ⬜️ ☑️ ⬜️ ☑️

   3.1. В функции успешно проходим условие, поскольку добавляли атрибуты в п. 2.2.

   3.2. Удаляем чекбоксам атрибут `checked`. Браузер изменяет состояние на *выкл* только у 4-го чекбокса, т. к. у остальных флаги равны true. Итог:

   ⬜️☑️⬜️⬜️
4. Клик по четвёртому чекбоксу: был *выкл*, стал *вкл*. Флаг изменённого состояния тоже становится *true*. Предварительный итог:

   ⬜️☑️⬜️☑️

   4.1. Попадаем в условие `else`, т. к. атрибуты удалены в п. 3.2.

   4.2. Добавляем чекбоксам атрибут `checked`. Браузер смотрит на инпуты, у всех *true* флаги — разводит руками, ничего сам не переключает. Итог:

   ⬜️☑️⬜️☑️

---

### Работаем с состоянием через свойства

Вместо `elem.hasAttribute` мы будем получать текущее состояние чекбокса, обращаясь к свойству `elem.checked`. Для изменения состояния будем перезаписывать это же свойство.

Также для краткости я внёс несколько менее важных изменений:

- вместо передачи `this` элемент достаётся из `event.target`;
- вместо цикла `for` перебор элементов реализован через метод массива `map` (но т. к. `querySelectorAll` возвращает не массив, а объект типа `NodeList`, мы [одолжим метод](https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply#%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) у прототипа массива);
- вместо `if` использован [тернарный оператор](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA).

```js
function have_check() {
    var elem = event.target;
    var elems_group = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="' + elem.value +
        '"]');

    Array.prototype.map.call(elems_group, function(checkbox) {
        checkbox.checked = elem.checked;
        checkbox.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = elem.checked ? 'white' : 'red';
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Дата</th>
        <th>Сборщик</th>
        <th>Сумма</th>
        <th>Загрузить</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13.05.2018</td>
        <td>Сбербанк</td>
        <td>337.35</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1_2" onclick="have_check()" checked>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>18.05.2018</td>
        <td>Сбербанк</td>
        <td>248.9</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1_2" onclick="have_check()" checked>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21.05.2018</td>
        <td>Сбербанк</td>
        <td>717.6</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1_2" onclick="have_check()" checked>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22.05.2018</td>
        <td>Сбербанк</td>
        <td>723.45</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1_2" onclick="have_check()" checked>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22.05.2018</td>
        <td>Альфабанк</td>
        <td>723.45</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2_2" onclick="have_check()" checked>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>24.05.2018</td>
        <td>Альфабанк</td>
        <td>655.13</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2_2" onclick="have_check()" checked>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21.05.2018</td>
        <td>ВТБ-24</td>
        <td>356.19</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="3_2" onclick="have_check()" checked>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>23.05.2018</td>
        <td>ВТБ-24</td>
        <td>554.20</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="3_2" onclick="have_check()" checked>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй не ставить аттрибут, а немного другой метод

`elem.checked = true | false`

```js
        function have_check(elem) {
            var param_value = elem.value;
            var elems_group = document.querySelectorAll('input[value=\'' + param_value +
                '\']');

            if (elem.checked) {
                for (var i = elems_group.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    elems_group[i].checked = true;
                    elems_group[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                }
            } else {
                for (var i = elems_group.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    elems_group[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    elems_group[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Дата</th>
                <th>Сборщик</th>
                <th>Сумма</th>
                <th>Загрузить</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13.05.2018</td>
                <td>Сбербанк</td>
                <td>337.35</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name='1_2' value="1_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>18.05.2018</td>
                <td>Сбербанк</td>
                <td>248.9</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name='1_2' value="1_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21.05.2018</td>
                <td>Сбербанк</td>
                <td>717.6</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name='1_2' value="1_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>22.05.2018</td>
                <td>Сбербанк</td>
                <td>723.45</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name='1_2' value="1_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>22.05.2018</td>
                <td>Альфабанк</td>
                <td>723.45</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="2_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>24.05.2018</td>
                <td>Альфабанк</td>
                <td>655.13</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="2_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21.05.2018</td>
                <td>ВТБ-24</td>
                <td>356.19</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="3_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23.05.2018</td>
                <td>ВТБ-24</td>
                <td>554.20</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="3_2" onclick="have_check(this)" checked></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! А вы не могли бы еще вкратце хотя бы объяснить, почему атрибуты себя так странно ведут? Ведь и галка установлена, и в консоли в браузере я вывожу html-код чекбокса и вижу, что атрибут у элемента установлен, а обработчик клика это игнорирует. Может быть вы посоветуете какую-то статью с более подробным описанием этой особенности атрибутов и свойств?
На будущее: работая с чекбоксами, лучше пользоваться именно свойствами, а не атрибутами?

Comment: В общем точно разобраться не смог, но менять атрибут через setattribute не желательно, ты уже это сам понял. И еще когда ставишь атрибут, также по стандартам нужно ставить только checked="checked". И еще что нашел это - когда через атрибут меняешь, ты меняешь состояние но не значение html  элемента. Вот ссылки https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=327020, https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-30233917, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832640/input-checkbox-true-or-checked-or-yes